# How to wrap loop and promise and break loop based on Promise value

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am trying to find a way to create a customize wait for some condition to happen. Something like below:

```
static waitForActivityToHappen(activityName: string, timeout: number) {
   const startTime = PageHelper.getCurrentTime(); // Get current time in milisecond
   while ((PageHelper.getCurrentTime() - startTime) < timeout) {
       browser.sleep(PageHelper.timeout.xxs); // Poll every 1 sec
       <Do some action here>
       element.all(By.xpath(xpath)).count().then(function (count) {
        if (count > 0) {
            <break the loop here>
        }
    });
   }
}
```

But this is not working. Please let me know how can this be achieved.

Comment: There's no such thing as `browser.sleep()`. There is however `window.setTimeout()`.

Comment: You can't use loop structures with asynchronous code unless you're using an ES2017+ `async` function and `await`. Instead, you have to schedule the next iteration from the current one (perhaps with `setTimeout`, but if the `element.all` operation is already async, it seems odd to artificially delay things).

Comment: @Pointy: He's using Protractor, which does indeed have [`browser.sleep`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.sleep). (He's not using it correctly, but it's there.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder learn something every day. Happy new year!

Comment: @Pointy: Happy new year! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use browser.wait function, it accepts first parameter as predicate function, so you can write any condition, and it will work as long your predicate function returns true/false or Promise that will be resolved to true/false.

```
static waitForActivityToHappen(activityName:string, timeout: number) {
    let waitForActivityToHappenPredicate = function () {
        return element.all(By.xpath(xpath)).count().then(function () {
            if (count > 0) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }, function (err) {return false})
    }

    browser.wait(waitForActivityToHappenPredicate, timeout, 'Some timeout message here')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use loop structures with asynchronous code unless you're using an ES2017+ `async` function and `await`. Instead, you have to schedule the next iteration from the current one. Here's an example of doing that:

```
static waitForActivityToHappen(activityName: string, timeout: number) {
    const startTime = PageHelper.getCurrentTime(); // Get current time in milisecond
    // Start the process
    tick();
    function tick() {
        browser.sleep(PageHelper.timeout.xxs) // Poll every 1 sec
            .then(() => /*...do some action here perhaps...*/)
            .then(() => element.all(By.xpath(xpath)).count())
            .then(count => {
                if (count > 0) {
                    // Done
                } else if ((PageHelper.getCurrentTime() - startTime) < timeout) {
                    // Try again
                    tick();
                } else {
                    // Timed out
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // do something with the error
            });
    }
}
```

If you can use ES2017+ features, that can be written with a `while` loop (which will get handled something like the above):

```
static waitForActivityToHappen(activityName: string, timeout: number) {
    const startTime = PageHelper.getCurrentTime(); // Get current time in milisecond
    // Use an async function so we can use logical flow
    (async() => {
        // Note `await` in the below
        while ((PageHelper.getCurrentTime() - startTime) < timeout) {
            await browser.sleep(PageHelper.timeout.xxs); // Poll every 1 sec
            /*...do some action here perhaps; if it's async, await it...*/
            const count = await element.all(By.xpath(xpath)).count();
            if (count > 0) {
                // Done
                break;
            }
        }
    })().catch(err => {
        // do something with the error
    });
}
```